# emailVerified & isEmailVerified functions do not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm basically having an issue where the user can sign in without verifying their email address (clicking the link sent to their email). My code currently looks like this & every time I enter "isEmailVerified()" it tells me that no such function exists.

```
    const fbuilds = [];
    const frooms = [];
    clearErrors();
    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
      alert('Please follow the link sent to your email address to verify your account.')
      fire.auth().signOut();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      switch (err.code){
        case "auth/email-already-in-use":
        case "auth/invalid-email":
          setEmailError(err.message);
          break;
        case "auth/weak-password":
          setPasswordError(err.message);
          break;
      }
    });
```

and my auth listener function looks like this:

```
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user){
        if (user.isEmailVerified()){ //user.emailVerified
          clearInputs();
          setUser(user);
        }
      } else {
        setUser("");
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is correct.  There is no method called "isEmailVerified" on the [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) object.  A look at that API documentation suggests that there is a property called [emailVerified](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#useremailverified) that you can check.

```
if (user.emailVerified) { ... }
```

Please remember to use code samples and documentation for JavaScript and not other languages like Java that might have different APIs.

Comment: in the comment next to `if (user.isEmailVerified)` i put `if (user.emailVerified)` I tried both methods and I am still getting errors.